# apache mod-rewrite backreference won't match

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I'm trying to test if the value of HTTP_HOST exists as part of the URI.
First, I capture the value into a backreference with:

`RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}"    "(.+)"`

Then I test for its presence with:

`RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}"  "/foo/%1/bar"`

If the 2nd RewriteCond succeeds, then remove the value in the rewrite:

`RewriteRule "^foo/(.+)/(.+)$" "foo/$2" [L]`

But, with a URI like:

`http://foo/localhost/bar`

The 2nd RewriteCond never matches, and the trace shows:

`applying pattern '^foo/(.+)/(.+)$' to uri 'foo/localhost/bar'`

`RewriteCond: input='localhost' pattern='(.+)' => matched`

`RewriteCond: input='/foo/localhost/bar' pattern='/foo/%1/bar' => not-matched`

So, why won't the %1 backreference match?  AND
Should rewrite:trace4 be expanding that %1 in the 2nd RewriteCond?

Comment: "with a URI like: `http://foo/localhost/bar`" - I assume you mean a URI like `http://localhost/foo/localhost/bar` (you seem to be missing the _hostname_)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Apache backreferences in the regex itself (for the same reason you cannot use `%{VAR}` syntax directly in the regex). In the regex `/foo/%1/bar` the characters `%` and `1` are matched literally. (If Apache performed some kind of variable expansion before applying the regex - which it doesn't - then it wouldn't strictly be a PCRE-regex.)

(Which is why you are not seeing `%1` expanded in the log. Regardless of the LogLevel.)

You can, however, use an internal backreference (regex-syntax) to match the requested hostname (`HTTP_HOST`) with the 2nd path-segment in the requested URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}@$1 ^([^@]+)@\1$
RewriteRule ^foo/([^/]+)/(.+) foo/$2 [L]
```

Note that I changed the first capturing group from `.+` to `[^/]+` since this is only intended to match a single path-segment. Otherwise, if you had the URL `/foo/localhost/bar/baz` then `localhost/bar` would be captured (since `+` is *greedy*), which would fail to match the hostname (when it perhaps should).

(Aside: No need to surround all the arguments in `"`, unless it contains spaces. Too many `"` arguably makes it harder to read IMO. And I removed the unnecessary trailing `$` on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.)

In the *TestString* `%{HTTP_HOST}@$1` (an "ordinary" string that supports variable expansion):

- `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the requested `Host` header
- `@` is just an arbitrary character that is not expected to appear in the either the hostname or path-segment
- `$1` is the value of the first backreference (the second path-segment) as captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

The *TestString* is then matched against the regex `^([^@]+)@\1$` where:

- `([^@]+)` Matches (and captures) against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable.
- `@` matches the literal `@` in the *TestString*.
- `\1` is an internal backreference (in the regex itself) that matches against the first capturing group in the regex, ie. the value captured by `([^@]+)` (above).

So, a request of the form `http://localhost/foo/localhost/bar` (which is what I assume you meant in the question) would result in a *condition* that tests:

- `localhost@localhost` against the regex `^([^@]+)@\1$` - successful

Whereas, a request for the form `http://localhost/foo/something/bar` would result in:

- `localhost@something` =~ `^([^@]+)@\1$` - FAIL

---

*Aside:*

However, there could be other issues here, depending on what  (and why) you are doing here. If the resulting `/foo/bar` is a "virtual" URL-path then you presumably have a front-controller pattern in the `.htaccess` file also - but this rewritten URL is unlikely to be picked up by the front-controller - depending on how this is implemented.

If the resulting URL-path is intended to map to a physical file (eg. `/foo/bar.html`) then "malformed" URLs of the form `/foo/localhost/localhost/bar.html` would also map to the same resource (potentially creating a duplicate content issue). This could be resolved by either using the `END` flag (on Apache 2.4+) to prevent further rewrites, or perhaps test for the existence of the file before rewriting.